# Simplifying equation with $\exp, \sin, \cos, \mathrm{R, C}$

Tags: calculus

I've got the equation:
$$e^{\frac{-t}{R\,C}}\,\dfrac{U}{R}\left(\dfrac{1}{{(R\,C)}^{-2}+\omega^2}\,\left(-\dfrac{1}{R\,C}+e^{\frac{t}{R\,C}}\left(\dfrac{1}{R\,C}\,\cos(\omega\,t)+\omega\sin(\omega\,t)\right)\right)\right)$$ According to MATLAB that expression should equal for all $R, C, U, t>0$:
$$\dfrac{U}{\omega\,R}\,\sin(t\,\omega)$$

Is this right? I don't see how t0 get there through all these fractions. I barely can think about some complex relations.

Probably This question doesn't count to Calculus, but I didn't know where to put it.

Comment: Is $\omega$ real?

Comment: I guess MATLAB treats all their symbolic numbers as complex if not defined differently, but doesn't matter anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $U=R=C=1$, your expression simplifies to
$$
\dfrac{1}{1+\omega^2}\,\left(-e^{-t}+\cos(\omega\,t)+\omega\sin(\omega\,t)\right)
$$
which is different from $\sin(t\,\omega)$.

Hence, the two expressions aren't equal for all $R,C,U,t>0$.

Comment: Yea right, obviously. I was confounding something in the program. My "simplification" was for $C \to \infty$